# Getting Windows netsh hostednetwork SoftAP to use 2.4 and 5 GHZ

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-networking, internet-sharing, netsh, wireless-adapter

I have a Windows 7 PC setup sharing a wired internet connection over Wifi using the "netsh wlan set hostednetwork" command. It is working well but it is only broadcasting in at 2.4GHZ and would like it to also do 5GHZ. I have already made sure the wireless card is dual-band card. I have read both the [Wireless Hosted Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [netsh](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744890%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#bkmk_wlanSetHostedNet) documentation and do not see any frequency options.

I also have an extra 2.4Ghz only wireless card I can install on computer if I can force the dual band card to only operate at 5Ghz. Even if I could though, the netsh command doesn't have an option to pick a NIC from what I can see.

Not sure what to look into next, any ideas would be helpful.